# Using CDN to cache parts of a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, http-headers, cdn

Considering i have some static modules (parts) of a webpage. Is there a way of caching them in the CDN, only those and not the dynamic parts?

Loading those static parts using javascript (sending an ajax request to a specific URL which can be cached in the CDN) would be a solution, but then search engine crawlers will not be able to read them, and neither will users with no javascript enabled.

Have you ever encountered this, and if yes, how would you solve caching of static modules on a page?

Answer (score 2):

Sure,
Assuming I got the question right, you can use Cache Headers to created object specific rules (http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/)

I actually work for a security CDN company and we have behavior learning algorithms that will do the job for you. There are other solutions as well, most commonly you will have a GUI in which you can dictate caching behavior.

Still, the headers are the most standard (if somewhat low-tech) solution.

Comment: You are most surely talking about resources like pictures or css/js. Consider the following context: I have a page where 50% of content is static html text, and 50% is dynamic html text. How can i cache only the static content?

Comment: Hi, sorry I just saw this.... You can set headers on a resource level (marking some as cachable and other as dynamic). The algorithms I've mentioned will do this for you - while also identifying all dynamically generated cachable content (which stays the same each time) and caching it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of a solution by reading on the server the request headers and check if it contains elements from crawlers (example : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en ) and render differently the content. All in all i can tell an user: Hey access my site only with javascript enabled, but i really can't tell it to a crawler.